# Manage height between two components

Tags: css, angular

I have a two angular components, which grows/shrinks independently. I just need to make sure the two components should fill each others height.

Image:

[image]

So if component A height is greater than B, then B should take the A's height and viz versa.

Currently I'm getting like the right one in the pic.

Any leads would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: I tried with flex. but still some how i'm not getting same height

Comment: show what you have tried then

Comment: https://scotch.io/tutorials/responsive-equal-height-with-angular-directive 

check the above link.